# Did Montag the Magnificent kill his victims onstage?

Tags: the-wizard-of-gore

In the 1970 film *[The Wizard of Gore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Gore)*, Montag the Magnificent has a magic act where he kills a female volunteer onstage in an incredibly violent manner, then reveals them to be unharmed. Then, later that evening, the volunteer is found, murdered in the same fashion as in the show.

In one shot, it shows the entire audience hypnotized during the show, as Montag does nothing, implying that he hypnotized them into thinking that the horrific act happened. But, then again, the deaths do happen later, which suggests that it might be a case of him hypnotizing the audience (and the victim) to believe that the violence didn't happen. On the third hand, it's implied that Montag may have genuine supernatural powers, namely hypnotism. All in all, it's a very confusing film.

Is there any proof of what's actually happening here?

Comment: "*Please, though, whatever you’re doing, don’t come into this looking for an explanation as to how all this shit is happening by the time it’s over. It’s not that Herschell doesn’t provide one — it’s just that he and screenwriter Allen Kahn don’t care if it makes any sense.*" - https://trashfilmguru.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/grindhouse-classics-the-wizard-of-gore/